# SVG Path rendering not consistent across browsers

Tags: svg, safari

I'm experiencing two different renderings of the same SVG path on two webkit browsers : Chrome and Safari.

Here is the markup :

```
<svg class="drillPath0" viewBox="0 0 775 310">
    <path fill="transparent" stroke="#000" d="M 100 100 V 0"></path>
    <path fill="transparent" stroke="#000" d="M 200 100 H 100"></path>
    <path fill="transparent" stroke="#000" d="M 200 100 V 200"></path>
</svg>
```

On Chrome, it properly starts from the top of the SVG element.

On Safari, it has a 100px offset.

There is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mjcrsg3/1/) ready if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to be a Safari bug, that has been fixed with the 7.0.1 update and iOS 8.